# SQL Server backup app

Tags: backup, sql, sql-server-express

We are using DPM 2010 to backup our Hyper-V cluster however we require an client/agent and server SQL backup app for all of our Windows VMs, as to purchase an Enterprise DPM licence for each VM is to expensive.

Any good ones? (Its need to be able to Backup MS SQL on schedule to a standard SQL backup file on disk)

Comment: Any particular reason not to use the built-in MSSQL backup / scheduling / agent functionality?

Comment: We are using SQL Express - Sorry should have said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can script a backup of the databases using SSMS and then save the script and then call the script from a batch file using sqlcmd.exe and then create a scheduled task that executes the batch file. Google is chock full of examples.

Comment: +1 DPM is more than happy to backup the BAK files created by SQL without additional licensince.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, DPM 2010 is good for windows base server. We are working with same from last many years. I do not found anything relevant than DPM 2010. But if you looking for something else, Please find the major alternative & competitors of Microsoft DPM.

1-  Azure Backup
2-  Dell PowerProtect DD (Data Domain)
3-  Rubrik

Source: https://www.peerspot.com/products/microsoft-dpm-alternatives-and-competitors

Or in some other case. you can try Stellar repair for MS SQL to perform SQL backup recovery, Password Recovery, Log analysis & database recovery from backup file.

source : https://www.stellarinfo.com/sql-database-toolkit.php

Thanks